# Hide shipping and payment methods in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment, checkout

I'm building a WooCommerce e-shop and I need to tweak my checkout page by doing the following:

1. Hide a certain shipping method (only one) if the order total > 100€.
2. Hide the cash on delivery payment method if local pickup is selected.

Does anyone know how to do that? I have the Code Snippets plugin so I can easily add any custom code.

Comment: It is possible using this plugin https://elextensions.com/plugin/conditionally-hide-woocommerce-shipping-methods-plugin/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To hide specific shipping method based on the cart total, you can use below code snippet. You need to update your shipping method name in the code.

**Disable shipping method as per cart total**

Add this snippet in your theme's `functions.php` file or custom plugin file.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'shipping_based_on_price', 10, 2 );

function shipping_based_on_price( $rates, $package ) {

    $total = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;
    //echo $total;
    if ( $total > 100 ) {

        unset( $rates['local_delivery'] ); // Unset your shipping method

    }
    return $rates;

}
```

**Disable Payment Gateway For Specific Shipping Method**

Use below code snippet. Update code as per your payment method & shipping method.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'x34fg_gateway_disable_shipping' );

function x34fg_gateway_disable_shipping( $available_gateways ) {

    global $woocommerce;

    if ( !is_admin() ) {

        $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );

        $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];

        if ( isset( $available_gateways['cod'] ) && 0 === strpos( $chosen_shipping, 'local_pickup' ) ) {
            unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
        }

    }

return $available_gateways;

}
```

Comment: @otpabu, If the answer solved your problem, can you accept it as right answer?

Comment: Done! Do you perhaps know a solution for my second question? The answer provided by ThallerThanYall doesn't work. Thank you again.

Comment: @otpabu , I have updated my answer. Can you please check?

Answer (score 1):

1. There are a number of plugins that will do this for you, take a look at this one [WooCommerce Conditional Shipping and Payments](https://woocommerce.com/products/conditional-shipping-and-payments/)
2. You'll want to tie in to the "woocommerce_payment_gateways" action

Something along these lines:

```
function alter_payment_gateways( $gateways ){

    $chosen_rates = ( isset( WC()->session ) ) ? WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' ) : array();

    if( in_array( 'local-pickup:6', $chosen_rates ) ) {
        $array_diff = array('cod');
        $list = array_diff( $list, $array_diff );
    }

    return $list;
}

add_action('woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'alter_payment_gateways', 50, 1);
```

The number on the end of 'local-pickup' on line 4 will depend on your woocommerce setup. You can find the string you need to put in here by adding something to a basket, going to the checkout, right clicking on the "Local Pickup" option in the delivery methods and looking at the **value** attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. It hides all the payment methods, not only the cod.

Comment: I see where `$list` is accessed in this script, but I don't see where it is initially declared.  I expect this script to break.  Where is `array_diff()` expected to find `$list` if it isn't declared in the function scope?